# Linking Linked Lists in c

Tags: c, list, hyperlink

I have 3 structures:

```
struct Product{
    int IdOfProduct;
    char *NameOfProduct;
    char *CategoryOfProduct;
    int PriceOfProduct;
    Struct Product *NextPtr;
};

struct Customer{
    int IdOfCustomer;
    char *NameOfCustomer;
    char *SurnameOfCustomer;
    struct Baskets *ListOfBasket;
    struct Customer *NextPtr;
}

*Header=NULL;

struct Basket{
    int IdOfBasket;
    struct Product *ProductList;
    int AmountOfTotal;
    struct Basket *NextPtr;
};
```

I took informations about customer from the user. I have customer's id name and surname. Now, the user can select one of the customers: The user enter the id of a customer that I listed by display function.So that, new basket will be added to that specific customer. How can i write this function ?

Comment: What you tried till now? Please provide the minimum working code

Comment: where dat list at?

Comment: i don't have any idea actually. I wrote addcustomer function. the problem is new basket will be added to that specific customer. user choice a customer by enter the id of customer than the basket will be added to that specific customer. I don't know how can i do that.

Comment: Vucko i don't understand dat list ? what does it mean ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the list of customers, I believe this is it:

```
void displayFunction(struct Customer *P)
{
     while(P->next != NULL)
     {
          printf("%d %s %s",P->IdOfCustomer,P->NameOfCustomer,P->SurnameOfCustomer);
          P = P->next;
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you but actually i don't want display method i already write that :)